# How to interpret loss values of fully connected model with large input images

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to apply [this example model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/2_fullyconnected.ipynb) to input images that are much larger (224x224 RGB). With stochastic gradient descent training I get initial loss values that are extremely high but then they drop to 0:

```
Minibatch loss at step 0: 85038.437500
Minibatch accuracy: 7.0%
Minibatch loss at step 500: 4275149.500000
Minibatch accuracy: 46.9%
Minibatch loss at step 1000: 6613.396484
Minibatch accuracy: 98.4%
Minibatch loss at step 1500: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Minibatch loss at step 2000: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Minibatch loss at step 2500: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Minibatch loss at step 3000: 0.000000
Minibatch accuracy: 100.0%
Test accuracy: 86.9%
```

I've tried to set the learning rate of the GradientDescentOptimizer to 0.1 and 0.01 but it doesn't help.

What does it mean for the loss to drop to zero? How can I prevent this? Is this model inherently not applicable to this input set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero loss means the model perfectly fits the data, and this is confirmed with your result of 100% accuracy.

That is actually pretty good, but I also see signs of overfitting, as the test accuracy is only 86.9%, considerably smaller than training accuracy. This means the model fits the data too well and is also fitting noise in the training data that is just not present in the test data. This means the model does generalize but it has some issues as the test accuracy is lower. If you look at the test loss (instead of accuracy) you will see that it is non-zero.

How to prevent overfitting? The model you are using is quite simple and seems it is not using any kind of regularization. Adding L1/L2 regularization, Dropout or Batch Normalization will surely decrease overfitting.